# Superset cache update strategy

Tags: apache-superset

Using the CACHE_CONFIG to configure the cache, CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT is set to 86400, which is 1 day. Within this day, will the dashboard data be retrieved from the cache on every access? Will the cache be updated when the filtering criteria change? Will the data in the cache only be updated after it expires? What is the update strategy for CACHE_CONFIG?

I would like to know the update strategy for superset cache